# What is the best way to read manga on Kindle?

Tags: kindle, conversion, image

I have a Kindle 5 and I would like to read manga (japanese comic) on it. What methods can I use? What format is the best and is there any converter that can create that format from a bunch of JPEG files?

Also, I have Ubuntu, so if a program is required, it would be better if it is available for Linux.

Comment: I second Kindle Comic Converter. I use it all the time to put cbr and cbz files onto my Kindle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest and simplest way is to use a [comic book archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_archive) format.

If you already have the image files, make sure that they are named with the correct alphabetical and numerical order (I.E. `cover.jpg`, `page001.jpg`, `page002.jpg` and so on); the program that you will use to read the comic will display your images in alphabetical order.
Then you can simply compress them in a `.zip` archive, and rename it's extension from `.zip` to `.cbz`. If you prefer, you can also compress the files in a `.rar` archive, but in this case you should rename it in `.cbr`.
Your ereader should be able to read one of these formats.

Alternatively, you can try [PDFtk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFtk), it is a nice tool for manipulating PDF in various ways; it is cross-platform (hence you can find it also in the Ubuntu repositories) and can be used to create a PDF from the source images.
I've always used it from Command Line, but on openSUSE repositories I found at least a couple of graphical interfaces, the packages are named `pdftk-qtgui` and `pdfchain`; I suppose that these should be available on Ubuntu as well, try to look for them (bear in mind that on different distros, the package names could be a little different).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution what I found is Kindle Comic Converter, which also cuts the edges. I used it several times, and worked fine (didn't cut into the text, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the JPEG files to a proper EPUB book as described in [this answer](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-can-i-automate-the-creation-of-epub-files-from-series-of-existing-jpeg-photo) and then convert that, e.g. with [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to the Kindle format.